# How to update the responses of the google form to the form itself

Tags: google-apps, google-forms

I am creating a Google Form. I want to insert a count in the end(anywhere,not specific) of the form which will show the number of responses submit till date.This goes like updating the live count. I have tried using script editor for Google Form Add-ons option.But I am unable to view the results automatically or changes. It asks me to accept "Terms of Service" which I don't want to do right now because I am not sure about the way it may result.

There are various options available to view the form results/responses.But here I don't want to view the results later.They should get updated when we click the submit button on form.Please note..simultaneously many users may fill the form.

To implement this,I have thought of logic like whenever submit button gets clicked..the text in the form should get updated.

Please suggest how I can add the count or apply above logic of whenever submit operation is performed. Is it possible?? Any other suggestions are welcomed..Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: There is no way to update a Google Form and keep it currently displayed in the browser tab.  You can't do it.  You can submit the form, create a pre-filled URL, and then re-display the form pre-filled.  But you would need to do quite a bit of programming for that.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I found another possible way of doing this..I received all the responses in Google Spreadsheet..which I later embedded in my site. Solves the purpose..And the embedded data gets updated automatically for the responses !! Cheers